# Notepad++ sources

Tags: notepad++, source-code

Is there a way to get Notepad++ source code?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, as it is open source software, you can.  [Did you look on the website?](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/)

Answer (score 4):

I think you may have luck on the [Sourceforge Project Page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/develop).